# Use htaccess to hide maintenance page on address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I want to redirect all requests to a single page showing "maintenance" I do the following in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

But if I want to hide **/maintenance.html** from url http://www.example.com/maintenance.html in the address bar how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [NC,L]
```

But in this case, there is no error code or redirection.
If you want a redirection, there is necessarily a change of url in the address bar.